# 3D reconstruction using stereo vison - theory

Tags: computer-vision, triangulation, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping, photogrammetry

I am currently reading into the topic of stereo vision, using the book of Hartley&Zimmerman alongside some papers, as I am trying to develop an algorithm capable of creating elevation maps from two images.

I am trying to come up with the basic steps for such an algorithm. This is what I think I have to do:

If I have two images I somehow have to find the fundamental matrix, F, in order to find the actual elevation values at all points from triangulation later on. If the cameras are calibrated this is straightforward if not it is slightly more complex (plenty of methods for this can be found in H&Z).

It is necessary to know F in order to obtain the epipolar lines. These are lines that are used in order to find image point x in the first image back in the second image.

Now comes the part were it gets a bit confusing for me:
Now I would start taking a image point `x_i` in the first picture and try to find the corresponding point `x_i’` in the second picture, using some matching algorithm. Using triangulation it is now possible to compute the real world point X and from that it’s elevation. This process will be repeated for every pixel in the right image.

In the perfect world (no noise etc) triangulation will be done based on

`x1=P1X
    x2=P2X`

In the real world it is necessary to find a best fit instead.

Doing this for all pixels will lead to the complete elevation map as desired, some pixels will however be impossible to match and therefore can't be triangulated.

What confuses me most is that I have the feeling that Hartley&Zimmerman skip the entire discussion on how to obtain your point correspondences (matching?) and that the papers I read in addition to the book talk a lot about disparity maps which aren’t mentioned in H&Z at all.  However I think I understood correctly that the disparity is simply the difference `x1_i- x2_i`?

Is this approach correct, and if not where did I make mistakes?

Comment: I have to admit that formulating this question in a structured manner already helped me a lot in understanding the topic. Since I would still like to know if this is indeed correct and I am sure it will also help many others, I decided not to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is in general correct.

You can think of a stereo camera system as two points in space where their relative orientation is known. This are the optical centers. In front of each optical center, you have a coordinate system. These are the image planes. When you have found two corresponding pixels, you can then calculate a line for each pixel, wich goes throug the pixel and the respectively optical center. Where the two lines intersect, there is the object point in 3D. Because of the not perfect world, they will probably not intersect and one may use the point where the lines are closest to each other.

There exist several algorithms to detect which points correspond.

When using disparities, the two image planes need to be aligned such that the images are parallel and each row in image 1 corresponds to the same row in image 2. Then correspondences only need to be searched on a per row basis. Then it is also enough to know about the differences on x-axis of the single corresponding points. This is then the disparity.